# How to Join multipe queries result in one query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sum, pivot

i will be so greatful if you help we the following topic :

```
select z1.nature_projet as typeCredit,COUNT(z1.nature_projet) as nbreTotalRejete, SUM(z1.montant_emprunt) as totalMontantRejete                                                 
FROM (
select * from dossier
where (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_affectation_banque ) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM now())) and partner_id=1 and statut_dossier='Envoye'
) z1
where banque_statut_dossier='Rejete'
group by nature_projet**
```

The following picture describe the result :

[image]

```
select  z1.nature_projet as typeCredit,COUNT(z1.nature_projet) as nbreTotalAccorde, SUM(z1.montant_emprunt) as totalMontantAccorde                                                          
FROM (
select * from dossier
where (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_affectation_banque ) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM now())) and partner_id=1 and statut_dossier='Envoye'
) z1
where banque_statut_dossier='Accorde'
group by nature_projet
```

the following picture describe the result :

[image]

```
SELECT z1.nature_projet as typeCredit,  
COUNT(z1.nature_projet) as nbreTotal, SUM(z1.montant_emprunt) as totalMontant                                                           
FROM (
select * from dossier
where (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_affectation_banque ) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM now())) and partner_id=1 and statut_dossier='Envoye'
) z1
group by nature_projet
```

the following picture describe the result :

[image]

i want to join the result of the the first two queries in one the result the last one , so the resultING COLUMNS  will be like  :

```
TypeCredit,totalNbre,totalMontant,TotalNbreAccorde,TotalMontantAccorde,TottalNbreRejete,TotalMontantRejete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. Consider:

```
select nature_projet, 
    count(*)             filter(where banque_statut_dossier = 'Rejete' ) cnt_rejete,
    count(*)             filter(where banque_statut_dossier = 'Accorde') cnt_accorde,
    count(*)             filter(where banque_statut_dossier = 'Envoye' ) cnt_envoye,
    sum(montant_emprunt) filter(where banque_statut_dossier = 'Rejete' ) montant_rejete,
    sum(montant_emprunt) filter(where banque_statut_dossier = 'Accorde') montant_accorde,
    sum(montant_emprunt) filter(where banque_statut_dossier = 'Envoye' ) montant_envoye
from dossier
where 
    partner_id = 1
    and banque_statut_dossier in ('Rejete', 'Accorde', 'Envoye')
    and date_affectation_banque >= date_trunc('month', current_date) 
    and date_affectation_banque <  date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month'
group by nature_projet
```

Note that I changed the date filtering logic; your seem to intend to filter on the current month, and the above expressions, using direct filtering against half-open intervals, do that more efficiently that your original strategy that relies on date functions.